# How do I have two elements inside an index when using python list comprehensions?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to fully capitalise a word as well as include its length in a new list, using list comprehension.

For example if I entered `wordLengths(["hello","bye","greetings"])` I am wanting this output.

```
[("HELLO",5),("BYE",3),("GREETINGS",9)]
```

This is my current code

```
def wordLengths(myWords):
    return [i.upper() for i in myWords], [len(i) for i in myWords]
```

And this is the current output

```
(['HELLO', 'BYE', 'GREETINGS'], [5, 3, 9])
```

Comment: This question could easily have been answered by cruising around stack overflow rather than submitting a new question... Anyway, you can [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) your return statement, i.e. ```return zip( [i.upper() for i in myWords], [len(i) for i in myWords] )```, or do any of the suggestions below.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do the both in one list comprehension:

```
[(i.upper(), len(i)) for i in myWords]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method is returning a tuple of two lists, and what you are actually trying to do is create a list of tuples.

Your comprehension would simply be:

```
[(word.upper(), len(word)) for word in words]
```

So, your method can now be re-written as:

```
def wordLengths(myWords):
    return [(word.upper(), len(word)) for word in myWords]
```

Demo:

```
words = ["hello", "bye", "greetings"]
print(wordLengths(words))
# outputs
# [('HELLO', 5), ('BYE', 3), ('GREETINGS', 9)]
```